# Calculating Indefinite integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose $f(x)=\int g(x)dx+C_1$,

Then how can I get $f(a-x)$?

I thought  $f(a-x)=\int g(a-x)d(a-x)+C_1=-\int g(a-x)dx+C_1$. But it seems not correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=a-y\implies dx=-dy$

$$f(x)=\int g(x)dx+C_1$$

$$\implies f(a-y)=\int g(a-y)(-dy)+C_1=-\int g(a-y)dy+C_1$$

Comment: Hi, But  if $f(x)= \int x dx+C_1=\frac{x^2}{2}+C_1$, then $f(a-x)=\frac{(a-x)^2}{2}+C_1\neq -\int (a-x)dx+C_1$. So what is wrong with my calculation?

Comment: @user91360, $$\int (a-x) dx=???$$

Comment: $\int(a-x)dx=ax-\frac{1}{2}x^2 $.

Comment: @user91360, If $f(x)=g(x)+C, f'(x)=g'(x)$

Comment: So I can I determine the constant term that differ in $f(x)$ and $f(a-x)$?

Comment: @user91360, observe that  $$ax-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{(a-x)^2}2=-\frac{a^2}2$$ which is independent of $x,$ hence constant

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I wonder for  general $f(\cdot)$, how can we calculate such term?

Comment: @user91360, don't bother about the form of the answer. In case of doubt, just differentiate the answer.